# Why my setInterval() autoreset after 30seconds?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a script like this:

```
<div id="my_div"></div>
<script>
setTimeout(
  function myFunction() {
    $('#my_div').load('example1.php');
    document.getElementById("header").innerHTML = "EXAMPLE 1";
    setInterval(function() {
      $('#my_div').load('example1.php');
      document.getElementById("header").innerHTML = "EXAMPLE 1";
    }, 8000)
  }, 0);

setTimeout(
  function myFunction1() {
    $('#my_div').load('example2.php');
    document.getElementById("header").innerHTML = "EXAMPLE 2";
    setInterval(function() {
      $('#my_div').load('example2.php');
      document.getElementById("header").innerHTML = "EXAMPLE 2";
    }, 8000)
  }, 4000);
</script>
```

It should be load the page every 4 seconds (0s, 4s, 8s, 12s, 16s, 20s, 24s, 28s, 32s, etc). But when I execute the script, the `setInterval` will reset after 30 seconds. I think there is a default setting, but how to change this setting?

Thank you

Comment: Your code is not clean at all.

Comment: There's no automatic reset of `setInterval`, so nothing to change.

Comment: what do you mean when you say `reset`?

Comment: Why do you mix jQuery and plain Javascript? `$("#header").text('Example 2')`

Comment: There's no `id="header"` in your HTML. So assigning to `.innerHTML` will get an error.

Comment: `the setInterval will reset after 30 seconds` no it wont

Comment: @Barmar - mix of jQuery vs plain is what I do as well ... anything that is easy without jQuery (almost everything) I do without ... things like `$.load` have a little more complexity (mainly if there's script tags in the resulting HTML) - so, rather than write my own "load" I would use jQuery - it's personal choice :p

Comment: Works correctly here: https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/v06ryquq/

Comment: Maybe your server has a rate limiter that's blocking the repeated requests to the same URL?

Comment: Check your Javascript console to see if the requests are being made and whether there's a response.

Comment: sorry that's just a part of my code in the page.

Comment: this should be load like this:

0s: example1.php
4s.example2.php
8s: example1.php
12s.example2.php
16s: example1.php
20s.example2.php
24s: example1.php
28s.example2.php
32s: example1.php
36s.example2.php


but when it comes 30s, the page is load example1.php.

that's the problem. Thank you

Comment: *setInterval* is not guaranteed to run at *exactly* 8 seconds, it will be queued so the two *setIntervals* may seem to converge, or converge then diverge. Why not have one *setTimeout* that calls the two *load*s alternately and calls itself at even 4 second intervals.

Comment: @RobG i thought it was like what you said, that this is just a bug or something like that. But when I use 4 example, what it should be=
 0s: example1.php 4s.example2.php 8s: example3.php 12s.example4.php 16s: example5.php 20s.example1.php 24s: example2.php 28s.example3.php 32s: example4.php 36s.example5.php........... But in 30s, the page is load example 1 again. So I think the time looping is reset to zero again. Is it correct?

Comment: @Barmar yup, from jsfiddle is work fine. but I don't know why in my case it doesn't work. Is it possible if it caused by some setting in my xampp?

Comment: Have you checked the console like I suggested? Also check your server access log.

Comment: Not a PHP question